# Recognize when loading of hasMany relationship is finished

Tags: ember.js, promise

I've got two models, connected with a async hasMany relationship:

```
App.Car = DS.Model.extend({
  model: DS.attr('string'),
  passengers: DS.hasMany('passenger', { async: true }
});
```

and

```
App.Passenger = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

How can I observe the loading status of a cars passenger? I tried:

```
App.CarPassengerController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['cars'],
  carsBinding: 'controllers.cars',

  loadObserver: function() {
    console.log('passengers loading status of changed');
  }.observes('cars.@each.passengers.isFulfilled')
});
```

This doesn't work, as the observer is only fired after the cars are loaded, but not after the promises are fulfilled. (I know they are fulfilled, because this is indicated in the Ember Inspector.)

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution for it? Thanks!

Comment: Another approach may be to send an action to your controller after the data is loaded.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Assuming your fetching the data in a route the guide illustrates how [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_send).  Why do you want to know when the hasMany relationship is fully loaded? - perhaps there are other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's gotta be a better way than this (and I'd be interested in knowing too), but this is how I've been doing it (hacking it, really) so far:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    var cars = model.get('cars')
    var carCount = cars.get('length')
    var carIterator = 0

    cars.forEach(function(car){
        car.get('passengers').then(function(passengers){
            carIterator++;
            if(carIterator == carCount) {
                // all passengers from all cars have been loaded
                controller.set('passengers_loaded', true)
            }
        })
    })
}
```